# How to implement an int3 handler to break execution in gdb, in a homemade kernel?

Tags: operating-system, gdb, kernel, qemu, gdbserver

**Environment:** qemu, qemu -s (built-in gdbserver); x86, homemade bootloader and kernel; QEMU read an hard disk image, which contains a bootloader, which load the kernel code.

**Goal:** Assume protected mode, and the IDT has been loaded. A line `asm("int3");` in the kernel source code should pause the execution in the gdb (remote debugging). (Implement a inline breakpoint for easy debugging)

I think `asm("int3")` is just like other interruptions, it calls a handler which can be specified in the IDT table.

**Question:** How to implement this handler?

e.g. Calling some API of the qemu gdbserver? I/O some serial port? Is this the correct direction?

Any information, thoughts, relevant document or existing implementation is appreciated.